# I used Android Device Manager to lock my phone but now it will not unlock

Tags: password, locked-out

I have looked at the other questions about this, but none have yet to help me. I locked my phone using the Android Device Manager because the pattern had been put in incorrectly too many times. I have tried using several different passwords, yet it always pops up as being incorrect. Does anyone know any trick or something that can help me out? I really do not want to reset to factory setting because I have several very important things on my phone.

Comment: Well, you can unlock the device again and for that first restart your device and make sure that your device is connected over the Mobile Data/Wi-Fi network and then log yourself into the Google account associated with the device using your Laptop/PC and then head over to the Android device manager and again try unlocking. I am sure this time things will work out for you anyway all the best !